# How to add/use Action Script 3 framework in Android project

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I'm working on certain android project. I have found some framework that I need, but it is as3 framework. How can I use it in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are writing your application using Flash or Flex, you should look elsewhere for similar functionality. While you can call native Java code from within Flash, the reverse is not practical.